# Making tibble construction (of columns, rows and data) in R more efficient

Tags: r, performance, tibble

I wanted to create a mini project in R, namely the construction of a 7x7 tibble with random data inside.

The goal was to perform data analysis on the data inside the tibble. The outcome was successful, but...

**The problem is that** the way I created the tibble and the data inside it are very inefficient.

Are there any of you who can do the same in less lines of code?

I want to make each function **more efficient**:

- Creation of the row and column names
- Creation of the random data inside the data frame

The more methods, the better!

Many thanks

Here is my code

```
# --- OVERALL AIMS
# To create a tibble with columns representing days of the week
# Random numbers would fill the columns
# Laterm, perform data analyses on each day and each hour (row)

# --- creating a concatenate to make the days of the week column

days_of_the_week <- c()

for (i in 1:7) {
  new_element <- i
  days_of_the_week[i] <- new_element
}

print(days_of_the_week)

days_of_the_week <- as.character(days_of_the_week)

days_of_the_week = paste('Day', days_of_the_week, sep = " ")

days_of_the_week

# --- creating a concatenate to make the hours of the day row

daily_hours <- c()

for (i in 1:7) {
  new_element <- i
  daily_hours[i] <- new_element
}
daily_hours <- as.character(daily_hours)

daily_hours = paste('Hour', daily_hours, sep = " ")

daily_hours

# --- creating the tibbles with 7 columns, 7 rows, with random numbers

daily_scores <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100), col2 = sample(1:100), col3 = sample(1:100), col4 = sample(1:100), col5 = sample(1:100), col6 = sample(1:100), col7 = sample(1:100))

daily_scores <- daily_scores[-c(8:100),]

daily_scores

colnames(daily_scores) <- days_of_the_week
rownames(daily_scores) <- daily_hours

daily_scores
```

Comment: You don't need a loop `days_of_the_week <- paste('Day', 1:7)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one command by creating a named 7x7 matrix and wrapping it in `data.frame()`:

```
daily_scores <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100, 7*7), 
                                   nrow = 7, ncol = 7,
                                   dimnames = list(paste0("Hour ", 1:7),
                                                   paste0("Day ", 1:7))))
```

Output:

```
#        Day.1 Day.2 Day.3 Day.4 Day.5 Day.6 Day.7
# Hour 1    13    16     9    89    22    36    83
# Hour 2    79    87    51    75    31    73    46
# Hour 3     2     4    24    26    28    23     6
# Hour 4   100    58    45    63    84    80    59
# Hour 5    55    88    60     1    96    57    70
# Hour 6    54    17    38    40    56    37    76
# Hour 7    49    94    47    71    93    32    35
```

Data frames by default really dont like spaces in their column names, so if the "." really bothers you in the column names, you can correct it by:

```
colnames(daily_scores) <- gsub("\\.", " ", colnames(daily_scores))

#        Day 1 Day 2 Day 3 Day 4 Day 5 Day 6 Day 7
# Hour 1    13    16     9    89    22    36    83
# Hour 2    79    87    51    75    31    73    46
# Hour 3     2     4    24    26    28    23     6
# Hour 4   100    58    45    63    84    80    59
# Hour 5    55    88    60     1    96    57    70
# Hour 6    54    17    38    40    56    37    76
# Hour 7    49    94    47    71    93    32    35
```